Will having a chemistry minor benefit me in a material science PhD?
I'm an undergraduate physics major and plan on pursuing a PhD in material science, and am specifically interested in soft materials, nanotechnology, and polymers. I currently have minors in chemistry and math. I don't particularly enjoy chemistry, but I've so far excelled in my (lower division) chemistry courses. Would pursuing a chemistry minor in undergrad help me in a material science PhD? Or will I have opportunities to learn the chemistry I need through the grad program and research I'm doing?

Yes, no, maybe? Depends a lot on the program you go to and the quality and emphasis of the chemistry classes you take, and so forth. For soft materials and polymers, some chemistry background will likely help either get accepted in the first place, or more rapidly come up to speed in the graduate polymer courses.

As someone who works in Materials Science/Chemistry/Applied Physics.... the answer is a resounding yes. The amount of courses a minor typically requires will create a basis for you to gain higher level knowledge during your graduate courses/research. Which chemistry electives you choose will obviously impact how relevant it may be for you, but certainly continued exposure during your bachelors will be very useful if you are interested in soft matter, nano, and especially polymers. If you go down semiconductors/devices, etc..., then it will be less so.

@R1NaNo -Going at it the other way around, if they were majoring in chemistry and asking about a physics minor I would give an unreserved YES in that the thermodynamics and statistical mechanics from the physics department would serve them better in materials science grad courses (at least in my experience and observation of other students, albeit decades ago). But then I was also more on the semiconductor side...
